# How to follow up after a software exam

Tags: interviewing

I attended 2 exams for software company, after exam both recruiters said "the contact person is not available, we will inform you when we can next schedule you to speak with them.

I faced the same answers in two different companies do not understand what it means. I did well on the exam, but I didn't get any call from them. I would like to know what measures i should take to follow up in this situation.

- When is it appropriate to call them back and ask when I will be able to speak to this contact person?
- How should i contact them (phone, email, ect.) and how should I phrase my response?

Comment: What measures you need to take in order to do what? I'm struggling to understand your question at the moment.

Comment: To clear your doubts once make a call to them and ask them.But in most of the case you should get a call within a week if you didn't get a call for long time leave your hopes.

Comment: You didn't get the job. Move on.

Comment: Or... give them a call, say you're fine with not getting the job as you have others in the pipeline, but it's important you understand where you went wrong with your code and would greatly appreciate their input as it may help you in the future.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you explained the following situation:

- Interviewed at two different companies.
- Took software exams at both companies.
- Company said they will contact you for the next steps.
- You have not been contacted by either company.

You should allow one week to pass before contacting the company about the interview. After the week has passed I would call the company and ask "I interviewed on X with Y for the position of Z and I was calling to see if you have made a decision or have any additional questions for me."

I'm assuming the software exam was one part of the interviewing process. There are many reasons a company may not hire you regardless of how you did on the software exam. Working in industry is not like university where passing a test is the only measure of success.